# Does the direct sum of two real line bundles admit a non-vanishing section?

Tags: differential-topology, vector-bundles, line-bundles

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, and $L$ be a smooth real (non-trivial) line bundles over $M$, is it then true that $L\oplus L$ admits a non vanishing section?

Intuitively, I feel like the answer should be yes, since I think I should be able to take a global section $s$ of $L$, and then obtain a new section $t$ by "pushing the zeroes of $s$ around" so that $s$ and $t$ don't vanish at the same point. The section $(s,t)$ would then not vanish. I am having trouble making this precise; I also suspect that I might actually need compactness or something so that I can make sure the zeros of $s$ are isolated and can actually push them off.

My motivation for this, is that I'd like to treat $L\oplus L$ as a trivial complex line bundle (I am pretty sure I can equip $L\oplus L$ with a complex structure since it's structure group should be $GL_1(\mathbb R)\times GL_1(\mathbb R)$ which I believe embeds in $GL_1(\mathbb C)$, but maybe I am also messing that up).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$L \oplus L$ need not admit a non-vanishing section. To see this, note that the Stiefel-Whitney classes of $L \oplus L$ are given by
\begin{align}
    \omega_1(L \oplus L) &= 2\omega_1(L) \omega_0(L) = 0 \\
    \omega_2(L \oplus L) &= \omega_1(L)^2
\end{align}
with all higher classes zero for degree reasons. Now if $L \oplus L$ has a nonvanishing section, it splits as $L \oplus L \cong L' \oplus \epsilon^1$ where $L'$ is a line bundle, and consequently we compute
\begin{align}
    \omega_1(L \oplus L) = \omega_1(L' \oplus \epsilon^1) &= \omega_1(L') \\
    \omega_2(L \oplus L) = \omega_2(L' \oplus \epsilon^1) &= 0
\end{align}
so it suffices to find a line bundle $L$ over some manifold $M$ such that $\omega_1(L)^2 \neq 0$, and for this pulling back the universal bundle $\gamma^1$ over $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^\infty$ to some $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n$, $n \geq 2$ will do.

Comment: That is indeed unfortunate for me, but thank you for the counter example!

Comment: Have I then made made some mistake in the the conclusion that $L\oplus L$ can be given the structure of a complex vector bundle? If $L_\mathbb C=L\otimes \mathbb C$, then we have that $2c_1(L_\mathbb C)=0$, but $2c_1(L_\mathbb C)=c_1(L\otimes \mathbb C)+c_1(L\otimes \mathbb C)=c_1((L\oplus L)\otimes C)=c_1(L\oplus L)=0$, so I conclude this is the trivial complex line bundle? I feel like I am making some error here...

Comment: The reason the intuitive argument fails, for the record, is that a generic section $s$ of $L$ will have its zero set $Z(s)$ be a codimension $1$ submanifold of $M$, which is not discrete if $\dim(M)>1$. This actually sits nicely with Ben's answer. (Let me assume $M$ closed.) The line bundle $L$ is classified by its Stiefel-Whitney class $w_1(L)$, which is Poincaré dual (with $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients) to the fundamental class $[Z(s)]$ of the zero locus. (cont.)

Comment: To "push the zero set off itself" would mean something like finding a homotopy $s_t$ of generic sections with $s=s_0$ that ends up isotoping $Z(s_0)$ into $Z(s_1)$ s.t. $Z(s_0)\cap Z(s_1)=\emptyset$. However, we then have $[Z(s_0)]=[Z(s_1)]$ and the relationship of the cup product, transverse intersection and Poincaré duality forces that $w_1(L)^2=0$.

Comment: @Chris I don't think you can go from $c_1((L \oplus L) \otimes \mathbb{C})$ to $c_1(L \oplus L)$ in that computation, since this presumes that $L \oplus L$ is complex. Also, I don't think your claim that $\mathrm{GL}_1(\mathbb{R})^2$ embeds into $\mathrm{GL}_1(\mathbb{C})$ holds: $\mathrm{GL}_1(\mathbb{R})$ is just $\mathbb{Z} / 2$, so you're effectively asking for an embedding (of, say, topological groups) of the Klein four-group into $\mathbb{C}^\times$, but $\mathbb{C}^\times$ only has a single element of order 2, namely $-1$.

Comment: @BenSteffan How is $GL_1(\mathbb R)$ just $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$? Certainly it is $\mathbb R^*$ as the 1 dimensional linear transformations are just multiplication by $a\in \mathbb R$, and the invertible ones are those that are not zero?

Comment: Yes, $GL_1(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}^{\times}$, but it contains $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, so Ben's argument still shows such an embedding is not possible.

Comment: @Chris Right, I got slightly ahead of myself there. The argument remains the same: $\mathrm{GL}_1(\mathbb{R})^2$ has too many elements of order 2 (namely all tuples you can build out of $-1$ and 1). What I perhaps should have said instead is that since you have reduction of the structure group to $O(1)$ and $U(1)$, respectively, over a manifold, you may as well ask for an embedding $(\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z})^2 \cong O(1)^2 \to S^1 \cong U(1)$.

Comment: @BenSteffan Oh I see, the embedding I envisioned is actually not a group homomorphism...what a silly error. Thank you very much.